# probability riddle

Tags: probability

50 songs are played once each in a random order. Jack likes 44 of these songs. What is the minimum number of songs that will need to be played to ensure that there would be 3 consecutive songs that jack likes?

Comment: Not actually a probability question

Comment: @Henry, yes I think this is off-topic

Answer (score 5):

There are 6 songs that Jack don't like.  The worst outcome is that these songs appear as number $3,6,\dots,18$.  Thus, the minimum number of songs that must be played is 21.